# Mostrar todos los elementos de un slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente estoy empezando en esto de *JavaScript* y pues e decidido usar *JQuery* para hacer un slider, sin embargo, al agregarle al elemento la propiedad  $('.fondo').show(); solo me avanza un puesto en dicha posición de imagen y no me muestra las 3 imágenes que deseo mostrar cada que le de clic a el botón con que deseo mostrarlo, pero... si le quito el .hide del final si me muestra las 3, de que manera puedo hacer que me muestre las 3 pero que 1 no se ponga debajo de la otra.

Adjunto HTML:

```
<div class="grande">

<header id="header" class="header fondo bg1">
    <div class="botones">
        <button id="prev" ><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <button id="next" class="active"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="text-white text-center do">
        <h2>TO TRAVEL IS TO LIVE</h2>
        <h5>You dont need Magic to Dissapear, all you need is a destination</h5>
        <div class="ibfo mt-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn ds">SHOW ON THE MAP</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn ">MORE INFO</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<header id="header" class="header fondo bg2">
    <div class="botones">
        <button id="prev" ><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <button id="next" class="active"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="text-white text-center do">
        <h2>TO TRAVEL IS TO LIVE</h2>
        <h5>You dont need Magic to Dissapear, all you need is a destination</h5>
        <div class="ibfo mt-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn ds">SHOW ON THE MAP</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn ">MORE INFO</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<header id="header" class="header fondo bg3">
    <div class="botones">
        <button id="prev" ><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <button id="next" class="active"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="text-white text-center do">
        <h2>TO TRAVEL IS TO LIVE</h2>
        <h5>You dont need Magic to Dissapear, all you need is a destination</h5>
        <div class="ibfo mt-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn ds">SHOW ON THE MAP</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn ">MORE INFO</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    
    var prev = $("#prev");
    var next = $("#next");
    $('.bg2').hide();
    $('.bg3').hide();
    var items = $('.fondo').length;
    var pocisiondeI = 1;
    
    next.click(function () { 
       nez()
      
    });
    function nez() { 
    if (pocisiondeI >= 5) {
        pocisiondeI = 1;
    }else{
      pocisiondeI++;  
    }
    
    $('.fondo').hide();
    $('.fondo:nth-child('+ pocisiondeI +')').show();

    console.log(pocisiondeI);
        

    };

});
```

Ese dos es el número del slider que se muestra con el `console.log` del final de mi código de JS.

[image: Ese dos es el numero del slider que se muestra con el console.log del final de mi código de js]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios elementos con el mismo ID. Por ejemplo, la siguiente línea solo afectará al primero de los botones:

```
var next = $("#next");
```

Por consiguiente, tu función de [*click*] no aplicará a los 3 botones sino solamente al primero.

Es recomendable que utilices un solo código del [*header /header*] y que, a partir del click que realices tanto en {*prev*} como en {*next*} en el Jquery hagas el cambio de imagen. Algo como esto:

HTML:

```
<div class="grande">
    <header id="header" class="header fondo imgchange">
        <div class="botones">
            <button id="prev" ><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button id="next" class="active"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="text-white text-center do">
            <h2>TO TRAVEL IS TO LIVE</h2>
            <h5>You dont need Magic to Dissapear, all you need is a destination</h5>
            <div class="ibfo mt-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn ds">SHOW ON THE MAP</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn ">MORE INFO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Array que contiene las imágenes a mostrar con sus rutas respectivas
    var img_bg = new Array("img/img1.png", "img/img2.png", "img/img3.png");

    // Variable que sirve que control para saber cuál es la imagen a mostrar
    var imgpos = 0;

    var prev = $("#prev");
    var next = $("#next");

    // No hay imagen de fondo. Se asigna la primera imagen al div que contiene
    // la clase imgchange.
    // Nótese que el primer elemento del array comienza con cero
    $('.imgchange').css("background", "url('" + img_bg[0] + "')");

    // Al hacer click en prev
    prev.click(function () { 
        // Utilizamos un operador ternario para actualizar cual será la imagen
        // a mostrar. Se utiliza un decremento en 1 hasta que llegue al primer             
        // elemento del array img_bg. 
        imgpos = imgpos > 0 ? --imgpos : 2;
        nez(imgpos);
    });

    // Al hacer click en next
    next.click(function () { 
        // Mismo caso que en prev pero con un incremento en 1.
        imgpos = imgpos < 2 ? imgpos++ : 0;
        nez(imgpos);
    });

    function nez(imgpos) {
        // Asigna la imagen del array de acuerdo a la posicion actual de imgpos
        var image = img_bg[imgpos];

        // Cambia el fondo del div
        $('.imgchange').css("background", "url('" + image + "')");
    }       
}
```